Satellite slew rate with respect to a ground station
For a given satellite orbit and observation time, I have the vectors containing the elevation and azimuth angles of the satellite with respect to a ground station. I know that the elevation slew rate is the derivative of the elevation over time, while the azimuth slew rate is the derivative of the azimuth over time. I would like to compute a "total" slew rate, but I don't know how to do it. I would really appreciate your help.

Cross-site duplicate of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/58088/satellite-slew-rate-with-respect-to-a-ground-station (but it's more on-topic here, and doesn't have an answer there)

As noted, you already posted an identical question on another site. This is frowned upon, please make the question particular to the expertise available on each site, or remove it from the site where it is less relevant.

If "total slew rate" means the "vector sum of azimuth and elevation slew rates", you could do the following. Calculate the distance between two points of elevation and azimuth. This is done using the spherical law of cosines that was referenced. Distance/time gives the angular velocity the ground station slews, of which the calculated elevation slew and calculated azimuth slew are components of that total.

One of the problems with an EL-AZ drive is that when the target trajectory goes through the zenith, the azimuth changes by 180 degrees instantly.

You have to be very careful when comparing answers from different sources, because the same concepts are presented using a huge variety of unclear, conflicting, and overlapping names.
In this answer, I use a local "topocentric" coordinate system, with origin at the ground station.  Idealizing the ground as a smooth oblate ellipsoid with no terrain, consider the plane tangent to the ellipsoid at that point.  The unit vector in that plane that points along a (great) circle of constant longitude, toward increasing latitude, is North.  The unit vector in that plane that points along a (not great!) circle of constant latitude, toward increasing longitude, is East.  The unit vector perpendicular to that plane, pointing away from the Earth, is Up.  I intentionally avoid X,Y,Z because I use those to describe where the ground station is with respect to the center of the planet, which helps remind me that the directions E,N,U are different at every point on the surface. $\newcommand\v[1]{\vec{\mathrm{#1}}} \newcommand\m[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}} \newcommand\e{\varepsilon} \newcommand\a{\alpha} \newcommand\t{\theta} \newcommand\x{\times}$
Azimuth ($\a$) describes the rotation of a vector in the tangent plane.  It is measured from zero at North to $\pi/2$ at East, then $\pi$ at minus-North (South) and $3\pi/2$ at minus-East (West).  Another popular convention, which I do not use except only in this sentence to show the difference, measures from zero at East to $\pi/2$ at North, then $\pi$ at minus-East (West) and $3\pi/2$ at minus-North (South).  Elevation ($\e$) is the angle measured out of the horizontal plane, increasing towards the vertical (Up, at $\pi/2$).  Using these definitions of local spherical coordinates, the unit vector pointing from the ground station toward the satellite can be written in ENU cartesian coordinates as $$\v{p} = \m{\cos\e\ \sin\a\\\cos\e\ \cos\a\\\sin\e}$$
If you think that looks a bit weird, then you may be more familiar with a different convention for defining azimuth, or using a left-handed coordinate system, or other variations.  Which of them counts as clockwise and which as counterclockwise also varies based on whether you choose to look down on the plane from above or up at the plane from below.  The time derivative of this unit vector, using the chain and product rules, is $$\dot{\v{p}} = \v{q} = \m{ -\dot\e \sin\e\ \sin\a + \dot\a \cos\e\ \cos\a \\ -\dot\e \sin\e\ \cos\a - \dot\a \cos\e\ \sin\a \\ \dot\e\cos\e}$$
Because $\v{p}$ is a unit vector, its derivative is necessarily perpendicular to itself, as you can verify by plugging in to compute $\v{p}\cdot\v{q} = 0$.  $\v{q}$, however, is not necessarily a unit vector, since, for example, if $\dot\a = \dot\e = 0$, then $\v{q}\cdot\v{q} = 0$.  Instead, the magnitude of $\v{q}$, measured in radians per time, because that's what  $\dot\a$ and $\dot\e$ are, is precisely the "total slew rate" you seek:$$\dot\t = \sqrt{\v{q}\cdot\v{q}^\phantom{|}} = \sqrt{\dot\e^2 + \dot\a^2 \cos^2\e^\phantom{|}} $$
This approach assumes you know what the azimuth and elevation rates are, which makes sense because some measurement systems give you those numbers, or they are constraints provided to you as manufacturing requirements, or you know what the satellite orbits are and can then calculate the angle rates from the known position and velocity.  If, on the other hand, you have two vectors at different times, and want to calculate the average angular rate over that time difference, as uhoh assumed, here's how I would do that.
When you have good azimuth and elevation measurements of a satellite, that usually means you're using optical tracking, which gives no information about the range, so what you have is already a unit vector.  Radar can be used to estimate azimuth and elevation via monopulse tracking, but it measures them much less well than it measures range (time delay) and range rate (Doppler shift).
There are multiple ways to compute the angle from those vectors, but the most familiar suffers from numerical accuracy issues.  The place almost everyone starts is with the dot product, $\v{v}\cdot\v{w}=v\, w\cos\t$.  The problem is, that formula works worst with very small angles.  The root cause is the way floating-point math is defined: you can get much closer to zero than you can to one.  When $\t$ is tiny, $\sin\t$ can be calculated much more accurately than $\cos\t$.  That's why great circle distance is often written using the haversine formula,
$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\t}{2}\right) = \frac{1-\cos\t}{2}$$
You can also get $\sin\t$ directly from the cross product, $|\,\v{v}\x\v{w}\,|=v\, w\sin\t$.  However, that suffers from ambiguity: sine is symmetric around $\pi/2$, so $\sin 10^\circ = \sin 170^\circ$ and  $\sin 80^\circ = \sin 100^\circ$.  Cosine, on the other hand, changes sign at $\pi/2$, so that difference is obvious.  To be certain of quadrant, use both of them:
$$\frac{|\,\v{v}\x\v{w}\,|}{\v{v}\cdot\v{w}} = \frac{v\, w\sin\t}{v\, w\cos\t} = \tan\t$$
Compute this using the two-argument arctangent function, but be wary that some languages use atan2(y,x), and others use atan2(x,y)!
Further simplification can be made by noting that to compute the magnitude of the cross product, you don't actually have to compute the cross product, thanks to this nice little trick: $|\,\v{v}\x\v{w}\,|^2 = (\v{v}\cdot\v{v}) (\v{w}\cdot\v{w}) - (\v{v}\cdot\v{w})^2$, which works because $\sin^2\t + \cos^2\t = 1$.    If what you have is only azimuth and elevation, then both vectors are necessarily unit vectors.  That means, if we say $x=\v{v}\cdot\v{w}$, then
$$\tan\t = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2^\phantom{|}}}}{x}$$
Note that in this case, $x$ is a number very close to one, not to zero. For extremely tiny $\t$, even this sometimes fails.  The most accurate numerical method known, and the size of the errors made by other formulas, are described in this answer on my new favorite site, Computational Science Stack Exchange, which cites William Kahan, "Miscalculating Area and Angles of a Needle-like Triangle", 2014 (23 page pdf).  In the case of unit vectors (in Kahan's notation, $a=b=1$), we need $c$, the magnitude of the very small vector $\v{v}-\v{w}$; some arithmetic gives $c = \sqrt{2 - 2x}$.  The general result simplifies to
$$\t=2\arctan{\frac{c}{\sqrt{(1+(1+c))((1-c)+1)}}}$$
Important:  DO NOT REMOVE ANY PARENTHESES!  They are  there to ensure correct rounding behavior.  Compute the arctangent with atan2, and remember that the 2 in the equation is multiplying the result of the arctangent, not just saying you should use atan2.
Whichever formula you use, the angle you obtain is the difference between the lines of sight at the two times.  That's your $\Delta\t$, to divide by $\Delta t=t_2-t_1$ to find the average $\dot\t$.

Sorry for the late response. I want to warmly thank you, your answer solved my problem!

@CarlaC Glad to hear it!  In that case, please click on the check mark to accept this answer.


The derivation is slightly complicated by the fact that second order changes also needs to be taken into account.
I will post the complete derivation shortly.
However to derive the formula we need to assume small delta change in both azimuth and elevation and then doing a dot product between vector and new vector acheived assuming delta azimuth and delta elevation.
Note: This is hand derived and not taken from textbook. Hopefully I have not missed any terms

I guess that is another approach to get it. I believe some further simplification could be done.


For a given satellite orbit and observation time, I have the vectors containing the elevation and azimuth angles of the satellite with respect to a ground station.

I'm assuming by "vector" you mean a 3D vector pointing from the ground station to the spacecraft in some coordinate system.
And you have a series of these vectors, one for each time point where the position of the spacecraft is measured or calculated (simulated).
So if you have two subsequent vectors $\mathbf{v_1}$ and $\mathbf{v_2}$ with time $\Delta t$ in between, we can get the angle between those two vectors by taking the dot product as defined in which ever coordinate system you use1 between the normalized vector which yields the angle between the two, then dividing by the time between the two to get the average rate of change or "slew rate" between those two points:
$$\dot{\theta} \approx \frac{\mathbf{v_1} \cdot \mathbf{v_2}}{|v_1| |v_2|} \frac{1}{\Delta t}$$

1Ideally it will be some Cartesian coordinate reference system but if not, you just have to do some extra work to get the dot product.
2Left as an exercise to the reader is the addition of some smooth interpolation - which could be along the mean trajectory, or polynomials or splines for the vector components, or for $\theta$ or its rate of change.


What is the general formula for calculating dot and cross products in spherical coordinates?
Dot product of two vectors in spherical polar coordinates, do I have to convert to cartesian coordinates?


this looks the same as my answer.  the unit vector containing the angles, which points from the ground station to the satellite, is exactly what I called $\vec{p}$.  your equation is a finite approximation to my derivative, and you're missing an arccos for non-infinitesimal $\Delta t$

@RyanC I missed the last line of your answer - after seeing several inches of trigonometry I didn't expect you'd come to your senses at the last moment :-) Generally satellite positions are obtained numerically or via processing raw data for a grid of discrete time points. One might take those and re-interpolate with some polynomial, then take the analytical derivatives of those polynomials and pretend they are doing analytical math on a continuous function for sure, but that's just a numerical refinement to the approximation. This is a real-world problem - there are no infinitesimals.

@RyanC I've made an edit along those lines.

I have worked out the answer to the exercise you left, and added it to my answer.  That more than doubles the length, and links to a computer math paper I really like and want to share.

@RyanC Really good stuff! It's great when someone really digs in and writes a thorough and instructive answer, thanks! It will take some time to read through the references and links but I can tell it's good to know. As for "²Left as an exercise to the reader is the addition of some smooth interpolation  - which could be along the mean trajectory, or polynomials or splines for the vector components, or for
or its rate of change." For closely spaced points (those needle triangles) I guess just about anything would do.
